# geoserver v23.1 wms getcapabilites service exception

Tags: java, qgis, geoserver, wms

I have `geoserver` running on local host. `GetCapabilites` produces the following error:

`<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module @0x6183b039) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0x6183b039 superclass access check failed: class org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module @0x6183b039) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0x6183b039 </ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>`

running `platform independent binary` on `Ubuntu Desktop 22.04`, java is `openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18`

I am unable to connect from e.g Qgis

The web interface works fine. I only have one workspace, one store and one layer so far ...

Comment: Did you read the FAQ about running in jdk 17?

Comment: thank you @IanTurton :) I read `https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/production/java.html` and did `rm webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar`as suggested there. Now works. Do you want to do an answer? Or I can ..

Comment: You can do it ..

Answer (score 1):

As advised by @IanTurton I read https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/production/java.html

I then did `rm webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/marlin-0.9.3.jar` as suggested on that page.

Worked a treat, thank you :)